# How can I make UIButton stick to the bottom of the UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder

Sorry if this question looks dumb to you, but really:

I need to put a button on UIView, which contains UITableView as its subview. Right now, I have put it right below the UITableView using Interface Builder (By making UITableView a bit shorter, to accommodate UIButton).

As I compile and run the program, Button remains under the table, but I have to scroll the UITableView, as the table view contains more than number of rows, that iPhone screen can accommodate.

Is there any property of UIButton, by setting which I can make it appear at the bottom of the view, regardless of UITableView's height. Is there anything related to this in IB ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: So is your problem that the button moves when you scroll the table view?

Comment: Do you want the button to overlap/appear on top of the table view?

Comment: @DarkDust: No button is not scrolling i can say, it remains at the bottom of tableview.

Comment: So should the button scroll with the table view? I don't yet understand how you want it to behave.

Comment: @smparkes: I want the button constantly (fixed position) at bottom of the view, regardless of rows in UITableView.

Comment: @DarkDust: No, the button should not be scrolling, that's what I want. I am really sorry if my message is conveying something else to you.

Comment: @Krishna your first comment says the button remains at the bottom, and your second comment says you want it fixed at the bottom. So I don't understand what your problem is(or am I missing something?)

Comment: @aqs: Sorry, In first comment i wanted to say "It should remain at the bottom"

Comment: Checkout @smparkes answer below. Make sure you add the button after you add the `tableView`. If the button goes inside as the `tableView`'s subview, you can change that in the left side of the IB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have the following layout:

```
parent-view
   |
   +-- table-view
          |
          +-- button
```

So the button is a subview of the `UITableView`. Since it is also a scroll view, the button will scroll with it. To make it stay at the same location, you need to make it a sibling:

```
parent-view
   |
   +-- table-view
   |
   +-- button
```

Comment: Exactly as you figured out, Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to create a parent view with two subviews, the tableview and the button. You make the tableview frame the same as the parent view frame and then you set the origin of the button so that it appears at the bottom of the parent view. You need to add the button as a subview after you add the table view so it'll appear on top. Then want to let the table view/scroll view know that the bottom part is covered up so it'll let you scroll a little bit further down. Unfortunately, I don't have the syntax for that at hand ...

Comment: No, you don't have to code it but describing how to do things in IB isn't very easy in text. And, personally, I'm not great shakes at IB (I do code everything) so I'm not the best person to ask. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Thanks anyways :) Do you know, if Auto resizing, size and position, alignment or placement has to do anything with it???

Answer (score 1):

Like DarkDust said, you need to make the button at *least* a sibling of the table view. You could, if you want to have the button remain over multiple views, try this:

```
[[[self view] window] addSubview:yourButton];
```

This code will add your button as a subview of the application's window, so it will remain there until you explicitly remove it:

```
[yourButton removeFromSuperview];
```

Adding your button as a subview of the window will allow it to remain in its position regardless of the movement of other objects or views.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the button is inside the UIView and not in the UITableView? Dragging the button in interface builder could easily result in a button contained by the tableview.